# Restrict a geographic UILocalNotification within a timeframe

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, geo

I'd like to be able to schedule a geographic UILocalNotification, but only have it fire when the user enters that region within a specific time frame.

The reference does say:

> When you create a local notification, you must specify either a
>   specific date or a geographic region as the trigger for delivering the
>   notification.

however I'm wondering if anyone has any insight I might be able to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem possible. A better approach is to set the notification, then determine any region when the notification fires.